# A simple for loop

Tags: powershell

I am going through Jerry Lee Ford's book to study basic concepts of powershell and I have an exam coming up. I am however stuck at this for loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
Write-Host $i
}
```

The way I see it: 
$i equals 1 and as long as $i is less than or equal to then it gets upped by 1. So according to me, the end value would be 11 since the moment $i turns 10 it still matches the -le condition. However the end value is 10?

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's run through it:

$i = 1. `$i -le 10` is `true`. Print 1. Increment `$i` to 2

$i = 2. `$i -le 10` is `true`. Print 2. Increment `$i` to 3

$i = 3. `$i -le 10` is `true`. Print 3. Increment `$i` to 4

...

$i = 9. `$i -le 10` is `true`. Print 9. Increment `$i` to 10

$i = 10. `$i -le 10` is `true`. Print 10. Increment `$i` to 11

$i = 11. `$i -le 10` is `false`. We stop!!

So you see from 1 to 10.

But if you saw the value of `$i` outside the loop, you will see that it is indeed 11. But the loop stopped printing at 10.

Answer (score 0):

You're application reaches the for loop. It sets the variable $i to 1. Now it looks if the condition is met. If it is, the code inside the loop is being executed. After that $i is incremented.

So as soon as $i equals 11 the code inside will not be executed.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't figure that one out. Thanks guys.